# Tell sorbet about a Sequel Model's inheritance hierarchy

Tags: ruby, sequel, sorbet

I'm trying to apply typing to a repo that uses the Sequel gem. It's got a non-standard Ruby syntax for a particular use case: initializing a model when a table name doesn't follow a convention

Example:

```
# This is necessary to get around
# "Superclasses must only contain constant literals"
FooParent = Sequel::Model(:foo_bars)

class Foo < FooParent
end
```

I've been able to tell Sorbet that certain attributes exist on my Foo model with this code in `sorbet/rbi/shims/foo.rbi`

```
# Raises an error:
# "Redefining constant `FooModelParent`"
class FooParent < Sequel::Model
end
```

This makes errors such as "Method `join` does not exist on `T.class_of(Foo)`7003" go away, but I'm not sure how to get rid of this "Redefining Constant" error or if there's a better way. Can someone help me get rid of this error, or solve the inheritance typing problem a different way?

Answer (score 2):

One way to work around this is to use the `Sequel::Model.set_dataset` method documented [here](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/ClassMethods.html#method-i-set_dataset).

Ex.

```rb
class Foo < Sequel::Model
  set_dataset :foo_bars
end
```

This is all `Sequel::Model()` does as seen [here](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/e86e1ee72a52937b810d9c0b5de767e5b0a1b81d/lib/sequel/model/base.rb#L187-L193). This can still cause issues with Sequel's table validity checks, which can be fixed by calling `Sequel::Model.require_valid_table = false` in your Sequel initializer.

Thanks to jez on the Sorbet team for pointing this fix out!